# Regex Help to find FB User in C#

Tags: c#, regex, facebook

I am trying to capture the following url and parse the username with the following format:

```
http://lite.facebook.com/p/User-Name/0000000000/Facebook
```

This is the regex that I've used but when I parse through the text document it does not capture the username

```
FacebookLiteUsernameRegex = @"://[-_a-z0-9.]+lite.facebook.com/p/([a-zA-Z0-9.]*[^/?&]$)";
```

Any suggestions on why it's not capturing the username? Am I not grouping it correctly?

Comment: Try just `@"lite\.facebook\.com/p/([^/]+)"`

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the username might have other characters than a-zA-Z0-9 and most of your regex is not escaped, it might explain why you cannot find the value you are looking for.

By using the following regex, I managed to get the username. Hopefully iy will work for you as well:

```
FacebookLiteUsernameRegex = @"lite\.facebook\.com/p/([^/]+)";
```

Comment: There is no need escaping `/`, they are not special regex metacharacters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Based myself of Regex101. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, only use regex101 when proving a PCRE/Python/JS regex works (but even then it is not trustworthy at 100% cases). For .NET regex testing, better use a service that supports .NET regex syntax, like RegexStorm.net.